# Counting Duplicates from table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have got a table which i have mentioned below, i need to get a total results avoiding duplicates , can any one provide any assistance or suggestions on how to get the results mentioned below, thankyu

```
ID      name    Total   Used
24     John     5        2
24     John     10       6
27     Peter    20       0
27     Peter    20       5
```

Result should be something like this

```
ID      name    Total   Used
24     John     15       8
27     Peter    40       5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you just need to use `SUM()` on the two columns.  Also use a `GROUP BY` on the id and name

```
SELECT id, name, sum(total) All_total, sum(used) All_used
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, name
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6df6/1)

The `GROUP BY` field must include any other columns you are selecting which are not in an aggregate function, so for the example you would include both `id` and `name` in the `GROUP BY`.

Edit #1 your query would be:

```
SELECT [ID] , name, sum([Total]), sum([Used]), [GUID] 
FROM [table].[dbo].[vw_data] 
GROUP BY [ID], [name], [GUID]
```

Comment: tried the above query but getting this error: Column...is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @MrA are you adding any additional fields, if so then you will need to include them in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @MrA - Please don't cut bits out of error messages.  What does the whole error say?  And are you running exactly the same query or have you modified it?

Comment: @MrA The columns in the select list, which are not using any aggregate function must be present in the group by clause, Add all of your columns in the Group By clause who are not using Sum or any function.

Comment: still getting error , thats my final query: SELECT [ID]
      ,sum[name]
      ,sum[Total]
      ,[Used]
      ,[GUID]
  FROM [table].[dbo].[vw_data]
  GROUP BY [ID] , [name] , [GUID]

Comment: @MrA in your query, you have to include parentheses around the columns you are using `sum()` on, see my edit

Comment: yep all sorted , thnks everyone for help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(Total), sum(Used), ID, name
from table
group by ID, name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID,      name,   sum( Total,),  sum( Used)
from  table 
group by Id,name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id,name, sum(Total),sum(used)
from tab
group by id,name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name, sum(total) total, sum(used) used  from table GROUP BY id, name
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql syntax for this problem:

```
CREATE TABLE DUPLICATE (ID,NAME, TOTAL, USED);

INSERT INTO DUPLICATE VALUES(24,'John',5,2);
INSERT INTO DUPLICATE VALUES(24,'John',10,6);
INSERT INTO DUPLICATE VALUES(27,'Peter',20,0);
INSERT INTO DUPLICATE VALUES(27,'Peter',20,5);

SELECT ID, NAME, SUM(TOTAL), SUM(USED) FROM DUPLICATE GROUP BY ID, NAME;
```